# AMCL map->odom tf-transformation

Tags: navigation, husky, amcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

I have a question regarding the tf transformation which is published by amcl.
I'm working with a husky so i use the amcl_demo.launch file to start amcl.

[image: image description]

I build an tf tree for my lasescanner and the odometry of the robot.

[image: image description]

I'm using 2 static broadcaster for the transformations
base_footprint->base_link->laser

robot_pose is publishing the transform odom -> base_footprint

My problem is:
If i start amcl it is not publishing the transform from map->odom. I'm getting the warning
"Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:"
So in my understanding amcl should provide the missing transform map->odom to finish the tf tree. So why is it waiting for a transform between base_link and map?

Hoping for some help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49850/amcl-map-%3Eodom-tf-transformation/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oysster](https://answers.ros.org/users/49521/oysster/) on 2020-08-09**:
Hey Tirgo, i got the same problem. Would you like to tell how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not obvious from your description how you are loading the prior map into amcl. Are you running a map server in conjunction with it?

Also, could you post the output of amcl? You can modify your launch file to say

```
 <node pkg=... type=... node=... output="screen">
```

or find the appropriate log file.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0